# What happens to the coefficients when we switch labels (0/1) - in practice?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to see in practice what was explained here [what happens to the coefficients once labels are switched](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168637/logistic-regression-what-happens-to-the-coefficients-when-we-switch-the-labels) but I am not getting what is expected. Here is my attempt:

I am using the example of natality public-use data given as an example in "Practical Data Science with R" Where the output is a logical variable that classifies new born babies if they are atRisk with levels FALSE and TRUE

```
load(url("https://github.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/tree/master/CDC/NatalRiskData.rData"))
train <- sdata[sdata$ORIGRANDGROUP<=5,]
test <- sdata[sdata$ORIGRANDGROUP>5,]
complications <- c("ULD_MECO","ULD_PRECIP","ULD_BREECH")
riskfactors <- c("URF_DIAB", "URF_CHYPER", "URF_PHYPER",
                 "URF_ECLAM")
y <- "atRisk"
x <- c("PWGT", "UPREVIS", "CIG_REC", "GESTREC3", "DPLURAL", complications,  riskfactors)
fmla <- paste(y, paste(x, collapse="+"), sep="~")
model <- glm(fmla, data=train, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model)
```

This results to the following coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              -4.412189   0.289352 -15.249  < 2e-16 ***
PWGT                      0.003762   0.001487   2.530 0.011417 *  
UPREVIS                  -0.063289   0.015252  -4.150 3.33e-05 ***
CIG_RECTRUE               0.313169   0.187230   1.673 0.094398 .  
GESTREC3< 37 weeks        1.545183   0.140795  10.975  < 2e-16 ***
DPLURALtriplet or higher  1.394193   0.498866   2.795 0.005194 ** 
DPLURALtwin               0.312319   0.241088   1.295 0.195163    
ULD_MECOTRUE              0.818426   0.235798   3.471 0.000519 ***
ULD_PRECIPTRUE            0.191720   0.357680   0.536 0.591951    
ULD_BREECHTRUE            0.749237   0.178129   4.206 2.60e-05 ***
URF_DIABTRUE             -0.346467   0.287514  -1.205 0.228187    
URF_CHYPERTRUE            0.560025   0.389678   1.437 0.150676    
URF_PHYPERTRUE            0.161599   0.250003   0.646 0.518029    
URF_ECLAMTRUE             0.498064   0.776948   0.641 0.521489
```

OK, now let us switch the labels in our atRisk variable:

```
esdata$atRisk  <- factor(sdata$atRisk)
levels(sdata$atRisk) <- c("TRUE", "FALSE")
```

and re-run the above analysis where I am expecting to see a change in the signs of the above reported coefficients, however, I am getting exactly the same coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              -4.412189   0.289352 -15.249  < 2e-16 ***
PWGT                      0.003762   0.001487   2.530 0.011417 *  
UPREVIS                  -0.063289   0.015252  -4.150 3.33e-05 ***
CIG_RECTRUE               0.313169   0.187230   1.673 0.094398 .  
GESTREC3< 37 weeks        1.545183   0.140795  10.975  < 2e-16 ***
DPLURALtriplet or higher  1.394193   0.498866   2.795 0.005194 ** 
DPLURALtwin               0.312319   0.241088   1.295 0.195163    
ULD_MECOTRUE              0.818426   0.235798   3.471 0.000519 ***
ULD_PRECIPTRUE            0.191720   0.357680   0.536 0.591951    
ULD_BREECHTRUE            0.749237   0.178129   4.206 2.60e-05 ***
URF_DIABTRUE             -0.346467   0.287514  -1.205 0.228187    
URF_CHYPERTRUE            0.560025   0.389678   1.437 0.150676    
URF_PHYPERTRUE            0.161599   0.250003   0.646 0.518029    
URF_ECLAMTRUE             0.498064   0.776948   0.641 0.521489
```

What is that am I doing wrong here? Can you help please

Comment: What is the datatype of atRisk before and after you switch the labels?

Comment: It was logical and when I switched it was converted to factor. However, I ran the analysis when the atRisk variable  is "factor"  before and after the switching of the labels, and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: When it is still boolean can you then do 'atRisk<- !atRisk' and then compare?

Comment: @f coppens Ops! it is now solved. You  are right, it seems like the model does not like factors. When I changed the labels and kept the type of the variable as boolean, the signs changed.  I am new to this site, how can  I give you the credit of your answer now?

Answer (score 0):

its because you set `train <- sdata[sdata$ORIGRANDGROUP<=5,]` and then you change `sdata$atRisk  <- factor(sdata$atRisk)` but your model is using the `train` dataset, whose levels DID NOT get changed.

Instead you can do

```
y <- "!atRisk"
x <- c("PWGT", "UPREVIS", "CIG_REC", "GESTREC3", "DPLURAL", complications,  riskfactors)
fmla <- paste(y, paste(x, collapse="+"), sep="~")
model <- glm(fmla, data=train, family=binomial(link="logit"))


Call:
glm(formula = fmla, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = train)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.2641   0.1358   0.1511   0.1818   0.9732  

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               4.412189   0.289352  15.249  < 2e-16 ***
PWGT                     -0.003762   0.001487  -2.530 0.011417 *  
UPREVIS                   0.063289   0.015252   4.150 3.33e-05 ***
CIG_RECTRUE              -0.313169   0.187230  -1.673 0.094398 .  
GESTREC3< 37 weeks       -1.545183   0.140795 -10.975  < 2e-16 ***
DPLURALtriplet or higher -1.394193   0.498866  -2.795 0.005194 ** 
DPLURALtwin              -0.312319   0.241088  -1.295 0.195163    
ULD_MECOTRUE             -0.818426   0.235798  -3.471 0.000519 ***
ULD_PRECIPTRUE           -0.191720   0.357680  -0.536 0.591951    
ULD_BREECHTRUE           -0.749237   0.178129  -4.206 2.60e-05 ***
URF_DIABTRUE              0.346467   0.287514   1.205 0.228187    
URF_CHYPERTRUE           -0.560025   0.389678  -1.437 0.150676    
URF_PHYPERTRUE           -0.161599   0.250003  -0.646 0.518029    
URF_ECLAMTRUE            -0.498064   0.776948  -0.641 0.521489    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2698.7  on 14211  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2463.0  on 14198  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2491

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Comment: No, even when i change it, I still have the train subset as a part of the sdata. The problem was with changing the type of the atRisk variable from logical to factor.

Comment: I don't think thats the problem. It works with logicals and factors. In your code you made changes to ``sdata`` but this will not change your ``train`` data. Its like if you did ``x<-5; y<-x; x<-x+1`` x will be 6, but y will still be 5.

Comment: bu when I switch the labels in `sdata`, I run the code and my `train` data will be subsetted from the switched `sdata`